# Drawing a straight line using mouse events on canvas in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I want to draw a straight line. I achieved to draw dots when i click on canvas and move my cursor and also it stop drawing when i release my mouse button.

But I need to draw straight line. I find solution on stackoverflow but they are in Jquery and Javascript. I don't want to use JQuery.

Some solution suggest that create 2 canvas 1 for store line and 1 for drawing lines on canvas.

But I know that it can be achieved by single canvas and I am very close to achieve this.

following is my code.

```
export default class CanvasComponent extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        isDown: false
    }
    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>

            <canvas id="canvas" ref="canvas"
                    width={640}
                    height={425}
                    onMouseDown={
                        e => {
                            let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                            this.handleMouseDown(nativeEvent);
                        }}
                    onMouseMove={
                        e => {
                            let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                            this.handleMouseMove(nativeEvent);
                        }}



                    onMouseUp={
                        e => {
                            let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                            this.handleMouseUp(nativeEvent);
                        }}
            />
        </div>


    );
}

handleMouseDown(event){
    console.log(event);

    this.setState({
        isDown: true
    },()=>{

        const canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas);

        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        console.log(x,y);
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x+1,y+1);
        ctx.stroke();
    })
}
handleMouseMove(event){
    if(this.state.isDown){
        const canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas);
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x+1,y+1);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

}
handleMouseUp(){
    this.setState({
        isDown: false
    })
}
componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200,255,255)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 425);
}
```

}

Comment: You are going to have a Class variable for the "lastX" and "lastY".  The on move, draw a line from the last x and last y tot he current x and y, then save the current x/y as the last x/y.  You may also want to only do this so many times per second, as mouse events happen very VERY fast sometimes and your drawing code will stutter.

Answer (score 2):

you need to store the previous point in state. In handleMouseUp(i.e. OnMouseUp) event, you need to draw the lines between previous point and current point. here is the changed code:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class canvas extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //added state 
        this.state={
            isDown: false,
            previousPointX:'',
            previousPointY:''
        }
        this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>    
                <canvas id="canvas" ref="canvas"
                        width={640}
                        height={425}
                        onMouseDown={
                            e => {
                                let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                                this.handleMouseDown(nativeEvent);
                            }}
                        onMouseMove={
                            e => {
                                let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                                this.handleMouseMove(nativeEvent);
                            }}    
                        onMouseUp={
                            e => {
                                let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                                this.handleMouseUp(nativeEvent);
                            }}
                />
            </div>    
        );
    }

    handleMouseDown(event){ //added code here
        console.log(event);    
        this.setState({
            isDown: true,
            previousPointX:event.offsetX,
            previousPointY:event.offsetY
        },()=>{    
            const canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas);    
            var x = event.offsetX;
            var y = event.offsetY;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            console.log(x,y);
            ctx.moveTo(x,y);
            ctx.lineTo(x+1,y+1);
            ctx.stroke();
        })
    }
    handleMouseMove(event){

    }
    handleMouseUp(event){
        this.setState({
            isDown: false
        });
        //if(this.state.isDown){
            const canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas);
            var x = event.offsetX;
            var y = event.offsetY;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.moveTo(this.state.previousPointX,this.state.previousPointY);
            ctx.lineTo(x,y);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        //}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200,255,255)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 425);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the first coordinates as global or class variables, so you can draw the line on second click.

Do you need to show a temporary line when the cursor moves? Then add a second layer on which you draw a line with the same coordinates at every mouse move (clear the layer before redraw!)